# Instantiating new PDO sends blank response packet

Tags: c#, php, pdo

I'm building an API that will allow my Xamarin Forms application to talk to my web server running PHP. Everything goes well up until this line:

`$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, "guest", "", $options);`

After creating a new instance of the PDO object, a blank packet is returned. This isn't a problem when I try to view the same thing from a web browser, but it's almost like this one statement is causing a blank echo which makes my C# HTTPClient stop listening to the connection. Any suggestions on how to prevent this from sending a blank packet, or even to accept multiple response packets in a C# HTTPClient? I've already tried creating an output buffer before and after that line to see if that might help, but it doesn't.